# GWT RF: How to share the same code in client and server

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans, requestfactory

I would like to use the same code to sort and manipulate objects in client and server sides.

But I am facing a problem since in client we need a proxy interface representing the class of the server.

Is there a way to use the same interface in both?, I know RF has a mechanism to copy bean attributes from the server instance to the client instance when it is sent through the wire.

Comment: are you aware of shared package ?

Comment: Yes, i know, my question is why I have to use a proxy-interface (ItemProxy.java) in client and an implementation (Item.java) in server instead of using the same interface in both.

Comment: EntityProxy interface enables RequestFactory to compute and send only changes ("deltas") to the server.

Comment: yep, I using `ValueProxy` though, I'm not using a standard persistence model in my back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas says in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849602/gwt-rf-how-to-share-the-same-code-in-client-and-server#15852887), the only way in current GWT to have shared code in client and sever is implementing the same interface in both sides and using it in your shared code.

Since RF copies attributes from the server to the client as you say in your query, in theory we could use the same interface (the proxy one) in both sides (simpler code), setting the @ValueFor value pointing to itself.

Lets see an example:

```java
 // Shared interface in client and server sides
 @ProxyFor(Foo.class)
 interface Foo extends ValueProxy {
    String getBar();
 }

 // Server side implementation
 class FooImpl implements Foo {
    String getBar(){return "bar";};
 }
```

As information, we use this approach in our product, so as we can sell 2 backend solutions  (one is based on GAE and other on couchdb).

The code above works for client code which does not create new values, but if you want to create them, it is enough to define a value locator:

```java
 // Say RF which locator to use to create classes in server side
 @ProxyFor(value = Foo.class, locator ALocator.class)
 interface Foo extends ValueProxy {
 }

 public class ALocator extends Locator<Foo, String>  {
   public Foo create(Class<? extends Foo> clazz) {
    return new FooImpl();
   }
   ...
 }
```

Unfortunately, RF does not deal with interfaces in the server side see issues:  [7509](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7509) and [5762](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5762).

But, as you can read in the issues comments, there is already a [fix](https://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1764804/) for this (pending for review). Hopefully it would be included in a next release of GWT.

In the meanwhile, you can use this approach, just copying the file `ResolverServiceLayer.java` in your src folder and applying this [patch](https://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1764804/diff/15003/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ResolverServiceLayer.java) to it.

Comment: Thank Manolo, I have patched the file and it works!. Let me know when the patch is released.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use the same API is to use interfaces that both your proxies extend and your domain objects implement.

```
// common interfaces
interface Foo { … }
interface Bar<T extends Foo> {
  int getX();
  void setX(int x);

  // setters need to use generics
  List<T> getFoos();
  void setFoos(List<T> foos);

  // with only a getter, things get easier:
  Bar getParent();
}

// domain objects
class RealFoo implements Foo { … }
class RealBar implements Bar<RealFoo> {
  int x;
  List<RealFoo> foos;
  RealBar parent;

  @Override
  public RealBar getParent() { return parent; }

  // other getters and setters
}

// proxy interfaces
@ProxyFor(RealFoo.class)
interface FooProxy extends Foo { … }

@ProxyFor(RealBar.class)
interface BarProxy extends Bar<FooProxy> {
  @Override
  BarProxy getParent();

  // other getters and setters
}
```

You can then use a `Comparator<Foo>` or `Comparator<Bar>` in both client and server side.

I generally only implement *traits* (*aspects*, *facets*, call them the way you like) that way though (`HasId`, `HasLabel`, `HasPosition`, etc.), not complete domain objects' APIs. I can then use `HasId` to get the key of any object to put them in a map or compare for equality, `HasLabel` for displays (custom `Cell`s on the client-side, error messages on the server-side that are sent to the client, etc.), `HasPosition` for sorting, etc.

Comment: Thank Thomas, I'll check this approach.

Comment: It works like a charm. I selected the other response though, because it's simpler.

Comment: Thomas, we have started using the same shared interfaces approach to reuse code between client and server. But we got a very weird issue. Everything works like a charm in GWT super dev mode. But when we make full compilation and deployment, we get an exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: IAppointment`. The exception is thrown from code: `EntityCodex#decode() --> ValueCodex#decode()`. One and the same method parameter `type` of `EntityCodex#decode()` of is resolved as `AppointmentProxy` in super dev mode, but as `IAppointment` in fully compiled app. We use GWT 2.6.1 and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The point of RequestFactory is that it *does not* do use the same type. Each request context describes a set of operations to perform when the call gets to the server (create and find things, then apply setters, then run service methods). As calls are described as just proxies to the real thing on the server, you need a 'fake' model object like a `EntityProxy` or `ValueProxy` to ensure that the only calls that can be made are getters and setters - and that sometimes, setters are not allows (when an object has been read from the server but before it has been edited).

If your models are simple, i.e. not holding other objects, but only string, date, and primitives, you can have both the entity and the proxy implement the same interface. However, if the model holds sub-objects, then this is more difficult - the only way possible is to leave out those getters and setters. Otherwise, you can't override those methods in the proxy type to specify the proxy version of that nested object.

Consider using RPC isntead if you actually want to reuse the same types on the client and server.

Comment: I understand your point. RPC is better for complex entities, but it is more tedious. RF services it's quite easier to setup and the other answer matches my requirements. Thank Colin.